# ggmap (github) installation issue

Tags: r, ggmap

I am completely new to GIS analysis and the ggmap package. I red that now to do geocoding using ggmap you need the ggmap github version and a google API key. I already got my API key. I tried to intall ggmap(gibhub) and but failed.

```
> devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
Downloading GitHub repo dkahle/ggmap@master
Error in length(file_list) > 0 : failed to create directory ‘.’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In dir.create(path, showWarnings = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, ...) :
  '.' already exists
> library(ggmap)
Error in library(ggmap) : there is no package called ‘ggmap’
```

I uninstalled ggmap, restarted R studio, reinstalled ggmap many times but none of these worked. I have done my research to solve this issue at my own but I couldn't find a solution. I would appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

```
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2019-01-24                  

- Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.0   2017-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 backports     1.1.3   2018-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 callr         3.1.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 cli           1.0.1   2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 devtools      2.0.1   2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 fs            1.2.6   2018-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 glue          1.3.0   2018-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 lattice       0.20-35 2017-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgbuild      1.0.2   2018-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 processx      3.2.1   2018-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 R6            2.3.0   2018-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Rcpp          0.12.19 2018-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 remotes       2.0.2   2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rlang         0.3.1   2019-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rstudioapi    0.9.0   2019-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 sp          * 1.3-1   2018-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 usethis       1.4.0   2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Comment: I don't use ggmap anymore because of issues like this for geocoding and have found [googleway](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to be much better.

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks for the info. I will play around with googleway. I fixed the problem by starting from the beginning and creating a new R project. Thanks!!